# Custom Context in Spring-WS

Tags: java, web-services, spring, javabeans, spring-ws

I am trying to customize the spring-ws servlet context in a similar manner as I did for my spring context. For the initial context (initialized when the server starts), I have extended the `ContextLoader` and implemented the `ServletContextListener` class, which is similar to what the `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` class does. I am able to customize the initial context by overriding the `customizeContext(ServletContext servletContext, ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext)` method, and add/remove optional context xml files based on properties. I was able to set this class as the listener in my `web.xml` file instead of the default `ContextLoaderListener` from Spring, and it works as expected.

I am looking to take a similar approach for the spring-ws servlet context (all of the beans defined in `WEB-INF\spring-ws-servlet.xml`), but I have not been able to find any solution to this. The only thing I can think of doing is having my custom context loader also generate an xml file with the 'optional' beans to include, and have the `spring-ws-servlet` context import this. However, this is a hack-job of a solution and I think there has to be a better approach. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to customize the spring-ws servlet context when the first web service is called?

I am using Spring 2.5.6 & Spring-WS 1.5.9

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  The `ContextLoaderListener` logic applies to root webbapp contexts, not servlet contexts. The Spring-WS servlet(s) can still access the root webapp context as you have done previously with your normal Spring servlets.

Comment: You can declare a separate xml file where you can declare your Spring-WS beans. Here's an example http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-ws-2-and-spring-3-mvc.html This one uses Spring Framework 3.x.x and Spring WS 2.x.x

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your responses. I understand that the ContextLoaderListener logic applies to the root webapp contexts, not the servlet contexts. I am trying to customize the servlet contexts. EX- I have several beans defined in my context.xml. These beans are loaded with the root webapp context. Then, I have endpoints defined as beans in my spring-ws-context.xml. Some of these endpoints are not needed unless a certain property is true or false, so I do not want to load them. I want to customize the servlet context (defined in spring-ws-servlet).  Endpoints mapped using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this. I created a class that extended the `MessageDispatcherServlet`, and overrode the `postProcessWebApplicationContext` method. In that method, I conditionally add in my optional context locations according to my properties. After this method is called, the parent calls the `refresh()` method on the context, and the additional contexts will be loaded.

Another solution someone suggested to me was creating a custom namespace, and create a namespace handler to perform the imports if the conditions were met.